# Error occur when upload file larger than 10MB

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.5

I want to upload file larger than 10MB but getting error

> Spatie \ MediaLibrary \ Exceptions \ FileCannotBeAdded \ FileIsTooBig
>   File `/private/var/tmp/phpfBe4An` has a size of 27.82 MB which is greater than the maximum allowed 10 MB

**Code**

```
$response = \DB::transaction(function() use($request) {
        $listing = Listing::with('car')->find($request->get('listing_id'));

        $fileName = rand(1111, 9999) . '_' . time() . '.' . $request->file('video')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $media = $listing->addMedia($request->file('video'))->usingFileName($fileName)->toMediaCollection('listing_videos');

        return response()->json([
            'success' => 1,
        ]);
    });

    return $response;
   }
```

I saved uploaded file to amazon-s3.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you adjust the value of `max_file_size` in the **config** file located in

`config/medialibrary.php`

if not set it, for example, to accept 30mb perhaps?

`'max_file_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 30,`

---

If you don't have the config file mentioned above:

Publish it by running:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Thanks to @Norman Edance for pointing this out

Comment: To publish `config/medialibrary.php` do: 
`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Comment: How do you catch that error `FileIsTooBig` Exception so you can report it in a pretty error message to the user?

Comment: thank you Mohammad kasra baba Demet garm dadash mancheto yidam rafte bood ino config konam? what the phase. how can I forget this config to my laravel library? خخخخ